# GetFields Operator

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

I'm using a function to get the field data from a list. I need to know if the .GetFields operator will just return the fields, or if it will actually populate them with the data stored there? I think it's the latter after reading on msdn but I have no clue and I've never used these "test methods" before :(. Any help is appreciated! (or even if you can tell me how to do a test method would help!)
Here is code:

```
   ''' <summary>
''' This function will return all of the fields for a certain class as well as the data stored in them
''' </summary>
''' <param name="list"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function GetFieldData(ByVal list As IList(Of Object)) As FieldInfo()

    Dim fields() As FieldInfo = list.Single.GetType().GetFields()

    Return fields

End Function
```

End Class

Here is code for creating newitems

```
  ''' <summary>
''' This function will create new Before and After objects
''' everything should be passed in as a IEnum
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Before"></param>
''' <param name="After"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
Function NewItem(Before As IEnumerable(Of Object), After As IEnumerable(Of Object))

    If (Not ObjectsAreSameClass(Before, After)) Then    'If object classes are not the same, send an error message, else continue 
        'Pop error

    Else

        Dim BeforeFields() As FieldInfo = GetFieldData(Before)

        Dim AfterFields() As FieldInfo = GetFieldData(After)

        ObjectCounter += 1

        'Now check and make sure the objects are not the same
        If (BeforeFields.Equals(AfterFields)) Then
            'Objects are the same so pop error?

        End If

    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldInfo` is information about the field, not including its value. To get the value you have to provide an instance of that object type. Here's an example that you can place on a form to see how it works:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim info() As FieldInfo = GetType(Form).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or 
                                                      BindingFlags.Instance)
    For Each item As FieldInfo In info
        Dim value As Object = item.GetValue(Me) ' Get the value from 'Me'
        If Not IsNothing(value) Then
            Debug.Print("{0} = {1}", item.Name, value.ToString())
        Else
            Debug.Print("{0} = Nothing", item.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This basically works. I have to modify it to be able to compare two list at the same time though. Thanks so much for your help!!